# FMX.ListView.TListView in Delphi 10.4 fails to free memory when reloading (even without bitmaps)?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, reload, tlistview

FMX.ListView.TListView in Delphi 10.4 fails to free memory when reloading?
This clear the list, but it doesn't free up memory :-(

```
if ListView1.Items.Count>0 then
begin
   ListView1.Items.Clear;
   {or alternatively try in loop}
   i:=ListView1.Items.Count;
   j := i-1 downto 0 do
   begin
      //(If there are no bitmaps - the memory also gets occupied)
      //ListView1.Items.AppearanceItem[j].Bitmap:=nil;
      ListView1.Items.Delete(j);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: If you include `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;` in the project source and run it with Windows as the target, when the app shuts down, what does it report that it has leaked?

Comment: @DaveNottage Thx :-) The problem was direct loading into TListViewItem
ListViewItem.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(SQLQuery1.CreateBlobStream(SQLQuery1.FieldByName('Picture'), bmRead));

This change helped:

Stream:=SQLQuery1.CreateBlobStream(SQLQuery1.FieldByName('Picture'), bmRead);
ListViewItem.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Stream); ListViewItem.Bitmap.Resize(48,48); Stream.Free;

Comment: Thus demonstrating why you should provide *complete* reproducible examples. Your question does not include the relevant code